# Android doesn't animate alpha if it's initially zero

Tags: android, animation, view, android-animation, alpha

I am trying to animate `alpha` of an Android view (two animations, both fade in and fade out). It all works fine if the view's alpha is initially 1, by default. However, I want that view to be transparent initially, hence I've set it's alpha to zero:

`indicatorContainer.setAlpha(0);`

Now, the animations won't work. It will never become visible. If I comment out that line, the view is initially displayed (which I don't want), but my animations works fine when I invoke them. I though it's something trivial but apparently it's not. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I've also tried a floating point `0f` instead of integer `0` after reading some API changes involving the `setAlpha` method, thinking that my call may be calling the incorrect overload, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  mRelativeLayout.setAlpha(0f);
    mRelativeLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //OR
            mRelativeLayout.setAlpha(1f);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was using simple animation like this: ` Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(indicatorContainer.getAlpha(), 1f);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                animation.setDuration(200);
                indicatorContainer.startAnimation(animation);` isn't there a way to do that?

Comment: Try  to set visibility property to invisible in layout xml. And before starting alpha animation call (your view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: it worked that way.. any idea why it wasn't working?

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue where `indicatorContainer` is `ImageButton`.
Below code fixes this very, very annoying issue...

```
// XXX: Does not work if just 0. It calls `ImageView#setAlpha(int)` deprecated method.
indicatorContainer.setAlpha(0.0f);
ViewCompat.animate(indicatorContainer).alpha(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One can try following, a more simple way:

view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

Answer (score 1):

This might be irrelevant to the OP but I thought I'd share it regardless as it might help someone out in the future.

Please be aware that if you're initial animation combines `animate().alpha(0.0f)` with a manipulation of the View's Y or X-axis translation (e.g. `animate().translationYBy(500)` you have to reset this property before fading back in (using `animate().alpha(1.0f)`.

I came across this SO post thinking that setting alpha back to `1.0f` was failing when in actual fact it was still working as it should, but the animation was occurring off screen because I hadn't reset my Y-Axis translation (*Homer Simpson *doh* moment*).

Handily, to easily resolve this issue, you can add a `AnimatorEndListener` to your animation for when it finishes (as @Nikhil Verma mentioned above) where you can add a single line of code to reset the X/Y-axis translation.

In the scenario I faced I wanted the animation to float down and fade out so adjusted the Y-axis & alpha accordingly. After it had floated and faded I set a Listener to reset the Y axis translation like so:

```
 loadingMask.animate().translationYBy(500); //starts animation by moving it down the screen
        loadingMask.animate().alpha(0.0f) //fades out
        .setDuration(1500) //over 1.5s
        .setListener(new AnimatorEndListener() { //when animation completes
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                loadingMask.setTranslationY(0); //reset the y axis translation
            }
        });
```

Now, when I want the animation to repeat again, I can set the alpha of my View to `1.0f` and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to kinda solve for this - *not particularly elegant, but manageable*:

1. Set the view to the initial alpha you want 0.0f or otherwise.
2. When the event occurs where you need the view to have more (or less) visibility/alpha - eg, right before you start an animation - at that point you can update the alpha and then run the animation on the view

I'm still getting some choppiness when the animation repeats, but this approach might work for scenarios where the animation is not repeated